# How do I fix this stack buffers nested too deeply error?

Tags: fortran, doxygen, fortran90, documentation-generation

I am using portable version 1.8.3.1 of Doxygen. As a newbie to Doxygen, I am facing problem creating documentation of my Fortran source code. The code is in Fortran 90 with around 6200 lines, and I am using doxywizard to create configuration file and run Doxygen if that matters.

I know Doxygen needs specific commenting rules for comments which I plan to add later on but for now I am interested in creating source documentation like call trees, variables index etc.

These are log results from Doxygen:

```
Searching for files in directory E:/test
Reading and parsing tag files
Reading E:/test/test1.f90...
Parsing file E:/test/test1.f90...
Exiting...
Stack buffers nested too deeply
*** Doxygen has finished
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the original question important information about the version was missing: 1.8.3

The problem is given as "Stack buffers nested too deeply"

In doxygen the error message is given as a result of to deeply nested call to the routine pushBuffer that uses a stack with a size of 10. One of the situations where this occurs when you have quite a few number of statements on one line like:i=1; i=1; i=1; i=1; i=1; i=1; i=1; i=1; i=1; i=1; i=1; i=1; i=1; i=1; i=1; i=1; i=1; i=1; i=1; i=1;

A bug report and a patch have been filed for this problem in Doxygen's Bugzilla (see Bug 695974 - Fortran: Stack buffers nested too deeply bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=695974 )

The bug is fixed in doxygen version 1.8.4.

Comment: I am using portable version 1.8.3.1 of Doxygen. I see your point that part of the output is not really sufficient to see where the problem lies but since the code is a part of an ongoing project, I am not in the liberty of distributing the code. Can you please list some problems "where stack buffers nested too deeply" occurs?

Comment: I didn't see the the error "Stack buffers nested too deeply" before. In the code it is used as a result of a call to the routine pushBuffer. The used stack there has a size of 10, this can be increased. From the code I can see e.g. the situation that this happens when you have quite a few number of statements on one line like:i=1; i=1; i=1; i=1; i=1; i=1; i=1; i=1; i=1; i=1; i=1; i=1; i=1; i=1; i=1; i=1; i=1; i=1; i=1; i=1; There is also a condition in the prepass phase but I don't see an example of this that fast.

Comment: A bug report and a patch have been filed for this problem in Doxygen's Bugzilla (see Bug 695974 - Fortran: Stack buffers nested too deeply  https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=695974 )

Comment: Yes, MAX_INCLUDE_DEPTH 10 was the cause for the error. I modified those statements with more than 10 statements in a single line in my code and doxygen worked like a charm. However using allocatable size of stack (like the patch for the bug report) is a better solution. How do I accept the comment as the answer to the question? Thanks.

Comment: albert, please edit your answer to reflect the correct cause. The text as it is now is rather not helpful for future visitors. I think it is pretty obvious why it was removed before.